# javascript D3: how to remove an entire script via d3 or javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this setup:

index.html contains

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

and I load dynamically into it (when a socket arrives) a file doing this:

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
    socket.on('load', function () {
        $("#div1").load("sources/load.html);
    });
</script>
```

This is working great, and gives me the possibility to add content to a page without refresh, etc. In those added files there is some D3 code.

Now the challenge is to remove that content that was loaded when I want. 
I try to do that loading another file (load2.html) which contains code to remove.

No problem to remove a content in the form:

```
<div id="div10"> HI </div>
```

Using:

```
d3.select(#div10).remove();
```

That will remove "HI". 
The problem is that I can not remove the "generated script". 
For example is the file loaded (load.html) is :

```
<div id="rm1">
<script>
d3.select("body").append("p").text("D3 tooooo!!!");
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                 .attr("width", 200)
                                 .attr("height", 200);

//Draw the Circle
var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", 30)
                        .attr("cy", 30)
                        .attr("r", 20);
</script>
</div>
```

coding

```
d3.select("#rm1").selectAll("*").remove();
$("#rm1").html("");
d3.select("#rm1").remove();
```

will not make any effect in the "d3 script".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question could be solved, making that d3 generates the id to be removed after. So in the first file loaded I changed the d3 code to append a div with an id:

```
var rm = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("id","d1");
rm.append(.......)
```

Then loading this in another file:

```
d3.select("#d1").remove();
```

Will do the trick.

So the problem was that I could not remove ids content that were not "created" with d3, but were present in the "html" code. 
Still in need to understand why...